Proof that all local operators that are linear are partial differential operators.
Recently in one course, the professor defined the locality of an operator as follows:

Let $T: C_{0}^{\infty}(R^{n}) \to C^{\infty}(R^{n})$ be a linear operator. $T$ is local if $$\operatorname{supp}  (Tu) \subset \operatorname{supp} (u),$$ for all $u \in C_{0}^{\infty}({R}^{n})$.

Then he stated the next Theorem without proof, as he said we won't use it :

If a local operator $f$ belongs to the space $Op(E_{1}, E_{2})$ (i.e. The space of linear operators that go from sections of the vector bundle $E_{1}$ to $E_{2}$) then $f$ is a partial differential operators.

I have some questions regarding this argument.

Is this a general situation that is not only reserved for linear operators that go from vector bundles to other vector bundles?
Is there a reference where I can find this result and proof for it? Although my professor said we wouldn't use it, the argument intrigued me a lot, so I wanted to see proof. (Also, if anybody knows how to prove it, it would be amazing to see your proof.)
P.D. For my part I am going to try to prove it on my own, and if I manage something I will post the answer.


Edit 1:
This is the solution that I thought of, I am not sure if it is correct and, to be honest, I am not satisfied with it (I feel it needs more detail or to be more rigorous).
Take the linear operator $T\in Op(E_{1}, E_{2})$ an alternative definition of locality to the one I wrote tells us that $T$ is local if for any section $s\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E_{1})$ the value $T(s)(x)$ at any point $x\in M$ depends only on $s$ at $x$.
So we want to see that this implies that $T$ is a P.D.O.
For this we take the trivialization charts $(u_{i},\phi_{i})$ with $i=1,2$ on $M$ around $x$ for $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ respectively.
That implies that the section $s\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E_{1})$ can be locally viewed as a vector valued function on $u_{1}$:
$$s|_{u_{1}}:u_{1}\rightarrow E_{1}$$
Same for $T(s)\in\Gamma^{\infty}(E_{2})$: $$T(s)|_{u_{2}}:u_{2}\rightarrow E_{2}.$$
Now due to the locality of $T$, then the value of $T(s)(x)$ at $x\in u_{2}$ only depends on the behavior of $s$ around a neighborhood of $x$, so all of the information outside of this neighborhood does not affect $T$. This means that in our trivialization chart $(u_{2},\phi_{2})$, $T(s)(x)$ will depend on a finite number of derivatives of s (if it is an infinite number of derivatives we break locality). So we can write T as follows:
$$T(s)(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}A_{\alpha}(x)\partial^{\alpha}s(x),$$
where $\alpha=(\alpha_{1},\dots \alpha_{n})$ is a multiindex, $\partial^{\alpha}s(x)$ are the partial derivatives of $s$ up to order m, and $A_{\alpha}(x)$ are smooth coefficient functions.
We just proved that in a local chart, the local operator $T$ is indeed a partial differential operator, but we need to see that this is also the case globally.
For this, we notice that our charts $(\{u_{i},\phi_{i}\}_{i\in I})$ are open covers of $M$ so we can take a partition of unity $\{\varphi_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ subordinated to our open cover.
So, we can define $T$ the in the following way:
$$T(s)(x)=\sum_{i\in I}\varphi_{i}T_{i}(s)(x)=\sum_{i\in I}\varphi_{i}\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}A^{(i)}_{\alpha}(x)\partial^{\alpha}s(x).$$
This is well defined as $\text{supp} T(s)(x)\subset u_{i}$, $\text{supp} \varphi(x)\subset u_{i}$, so $\text{supp} \varphi(x)T(s)(x)\subset u_{i}$.
Then all terms $\varphi(x)T(s)(x)$ are smooth and well defined. Also the sum $\sum_{i\in I}\varphi_{i}T_{i}(s)(x)$ is finite at all $x\in M$ due to the locally finite property of the partition of unity.

Why dont you ask your professor for proof/a reference?

He explicitly said he was not going to prove it. I asked for a reference but he told me he couldn't give me anything precise.

There's a proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peetre_theorem.
